# RSS 2.0 feed only showing first item

Tags: xml, rss, rss-reader

I have recently created an RSS 2.0 feed, [HERE](http://lbpf.me/community/dlc.rss)

I am trying to view the feed using [my feed reader](http://feeder.co/), however I am only seeing the first item. I am seeing no errors in the page source, and the feed is syndicated just fine with [Feedburner](http://feeds.feedburner.com/lbp-dlc). What is the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To distinguish between entries, all readers use the `<guid>` element for each entry. Your feed has the same `<guid>` value for all entries. So as far as what the reader knows, all entries are the same and just one.

Make sure *each* entry as a **different AND unique**  element and you'll be good. [W3C has a validator](http://validator.w3.org/feed/) to help you fix your feeds.